# How do I know what the KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPEs want?

Tags: winapi, wasapi

I want to write audio data that follows the correct subformat of a WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE object. Microsoft provides a list near the bottom of this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksmedia/ns-ksmedia-waveformatextensible

I can not find documentation on the subtypes. If I find KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT, what are the ranges of the floats?

KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_DRM? How do I deal with the drm?

KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_ALAW? What is ALAW even?

Comment: Names have evolved but meaning hasn't. KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT = MEDIASUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT = MFAudioFormat_Float and corresponds to WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT. You'll find more information and samples googling for these names.

Comment: that is good experience insight, so ksdataformat_subtype_ieee_float is just wave format ieee float. But the asker seem to be asking in general how to handle generally waveformatextensible subformats correctly, if possible.